# how to extract text from PDF between some patterns

Tags: python, r, regex, nlp

I have some thousands of documents (in German) in PDF format. I need to extract a portion of text from each one of them, which usually comes after date and ends before the Date, Location, Address info nearly at the page end. An example is attached. The text I need is highlighted.
[image]

What I tried so far is  `qdapRegex::rm_between`:

```
library(pdftools)
library(qdapRegex)
t1 <- pdf_text("textsample.pdf")
textIneed <- rm_between(t1, "Datum", ", den" )
```

which did not work. The output is the whole text content including Name, Vorame, etc. (I could live with the date 20.01.2019 at the beginning.) What I am doing wrong is not clear to me, as I am new to regex and nlp and cannot spot it reading the documentation of `rm_between` or `qdapRegex`.

My first problem is getting this working.

The further problem is, these documents are not standard, and some documents may have another type of info, e.g., `Ref:1234` instead of date before the highlighted area. This piece may be found in any page number of the document, so going for exact page numbers is not an option.

Is there any other solution, library, etc. which can be used to extract more or less this portion of text?

Comment: Do all the paragraphs you want start at a certain height on the page, or can that vary too?

Comment: that can vary, too.

Comment: You could try using my PDF text extraction package using `devtools::install_github("https://github.com/AllanCameron/PDFR")`. If you use `PDFR::pdfdoc()`  this should extract the paragraphs separately for you and you can filter them according to font, position, length etc.

Comment: Try `textIneed <- rm_between(paste(t1, collapse="\n"), "Datum", ", den" )`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this @Wiktor Stribizew, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Please provide the exact input to test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good simple answer to this. With regular expressions it is possible to capture the text in between, but the expression might get notoriously complicated, if you have multiple or complex patterns to match. Let's take your simple example and use some dummy german text and expect that you want to get everything between a date (formatted dd.mm.yyyy or dd.mm.yy) or ref:[at least one digit] and  ", den XX" but excluding the last word (location) before that.

I'll use the `stringr` package:

```r
# generate some text (with new lines)
t1 <- c("Du möchtest also den Text zwischen dem Datum 13.07.2020
        am Anfang und den Ort bzw. Datum am Ende extrahieren.
        Freiburg, den 13. Juli 2020",
        "Oder den Text nach einem ref:384 übernehmen bis zum Datum am Ende.
        Freiburg, den 13. Juli 2020")

# extract the parts
textIneed <- stringr::str_match(t1,
"(?:\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}.\\d{2,4}|ref:\\d+)((.|\n)*)\\s\\w+, den \\d{1,2}")[,2]

# trim white space
# (this could be done before extraction too, to simplify the text)
trimws(textIneed)
#> [1] "am Anfang und den Ort bzw. Datum am Ende extrahieren."
#> [2] "übernehmen bis zum Datum am Ende."
```

What I'm doing here is matching the first elements with `(?:\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}.\\d{2,4}|ref:\\d+)`, then capture everything including new lines between it `((.|\n)*)`, but not the last word `\\s\\w+` before `, den \\d{1,2}`.

To learn regular expressions there are several resources available, like [RegexOne](https://regexone.com)